# How to execute large SQL statement

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to extract data from a MongoDb database and insert them into a SQL Server table, via a NodeJS program.
However, when I run it, it gives me almost 1 million lines and a huge SQL statement (with multiple "INSERT INTO", one for each row to avoid any limit) but it doesn't update my table.

I also tried to save the whole query in a text file and import it as a script in SSMS, but the file is too big (~300 mo) so SSMS is crashing.

What can I do? How can I maybe divide my query into smaller batches (like each 100 000 records) or pause it?

Here's my code :

```
var sql = require('mssql');
const fs = require('fs');

var config = { user: 'xxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    server: 'xxxxx',
    database: 'xxxx',
    stream: true, 
    requestTimeout: 2000000,
};

exports.insertElementsInSql = function(elements, callback) {
    let dateStr = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    sql.connect(config, function(err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            var request = new sql.Request();
            request.stream = true;

          var query = "";
          var count=0;

          query = query + "SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF;";
          query = query + "DELETE FROM [xxxx].[dbo].[xxxxx];";
            for(var i in elements){
                query = query + "INSERT INTO [xxxx].[dbo].[xxxxx] VALUES ";
                query = query +"('" + dateStr + "'";
                query = query + ",'"+elements[i].OrgaCode+ "'";
                query = query + ","+elements[i].nbWidgets;
                query = query + ","+elements[i].nbTabs;
                query = query + ",'"+elements[i].Segment+ "'";
                query = query + ",'"+elements[i].SitesList+ "'";
                query = query + ",'"+elements[i].Columns+ "'";
                query = query + ") ";
                count++;
            };
            query = query + "SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;";
            
            
           console.log(query);
            console.log("The query INSERT INTO is complete. Nb of lines : "+count);
            fs.writeFile('request.txt', query, (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('Query saved!');
            });

            request.query(query, function(err, results) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Failure ");
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(err);
                } else {
                    callback(null);
                    console.log("Yay");
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

I get :

> The query INSERT INTO is complete. Nb of lines: 919045

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you trying to convert your data into individual SQL statements?  There are tools that allow you to query the data from Mongo and save directly to SQL without having to build that intermediate step.

Comment: Use Bulk Insert or BCP. Perhaps SSIS can do this for you as well? 900k separate inserts is ridiculous, especially when they are not parameterized. Your current code is also vulnerable to injection